# Can not load the `model1` function of the processR package in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter, correlation, processr

I am very new to the whole R programming and trying to follow [this tutorial](https://rpubs.com/markhw/processr), where the `model1` function is used to find the Andrew F. Hayes correlation between three variables. As indicated in the tutorial I have the packages installed:

1. `install.packages("devtools")`
2. `install.packages("processR")`
3. `devtools::install_github("markhwhiteii/processr")`

I have also followed the steps:

```r
set.seed(1839)
var1 <- rnorm(100)
cond <- rbinom(100, 1, .5)
var2 <- var1 * cond + rnorm(100)
df3 <- data.frame(var1, var2, cond)
head(df3)
```

accordingly. However, when running:

```
mod1result <- model1(iv = "var1", dv = "var2", mod = "cond", data = df3)
```

I get the error message:

> Error in model1(iv = "var1", dv = "var2", mod = "cond", data = df3): could not find function "model1"
>   Traceback:

and running

```
mod1result <- processr::model1(iv = "var1", dv = "var2", mod = "cond", data = df3)
```

> Error in loadNamespace(name): there is no package called ‘processr’
>   Traceback:

The strange thing is that the same code just worked yesterday and now it doesn't. I would appreciate it if you could help me understand what is wrong and how I can resolve it.

**P.S.1.** I'm not sure what `.libPaths()` is but for some reason it returns two paths on my mac:

- `/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library`
- `/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library`

does it mean that I have two installations of R and this is the main cause of the above issues?

**P.S.2.** OK. This seems to be Jupyter's fault as everything is just working fine in the terminal.

**P.S.3.** What seems to be working in the terminal is:

- `sudo r`
- `devtools::install_github("markhwhiteii/processr")`
- `library(processr)` notice lower case `r` in the `processr`

**P.S.4.** I'm not sure if this is Jupyter's fault.

**P.S.5.** I tried installing the packages on Windows as well. It was even worse. I can't get passed the issue:

> Error: Failed to install 'processr' from GitHub:
>     (converted from warning) cannot remove the prior installation of package ‘digest’

I think maybe the key to solving this problem is to understand what is the difference between these packages:

- `install.packages("processR")`
- `devtools::install_github("markhwhiteii/processr")`
- `devtools::install_github("cardiomoon/processR")`

Comment: Since the package seems to install as `processR` (upper case `R`), did you try `processR::model1(...)` ?

Comment: @steveb yes I'm pretty sure I have put everything correctly.

Comment: I see the issue, you need to install using `devtools::install_github("markhwhiteii/processr") ` as this is different from `processR`. The tutorial uses `devtools::install_github("markhwhiteii/processr")`. Once that is done, then `model1` should be defined.

Comment: From the documentation, the `.libPaths()` function gets/sets the library trees within which packages are looked for. It does not mean you have two installations of R.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a couple of hours of trial and error, I think I have a messy workaround, not a solution though!

- run `sudo r` in one terminal
- run `jupyter notebook` in another and open an R notebook (I suppose you have the kernel installed)
- now you should understand that the `devtools::install_github("markhwhiteii/processr")` and `install.packages("processR")` are two different packages and you gave install both every time you restart your kernel in the Jupyter Notebook
- install `devtools::install_github("markhwhiteii/processr")` first in the R terminal
- now in the Jupyter side you should be able to `library(processr)` and run `processr::model1`
- next install the `install.packages("processR")` on the R terminal
- now import the `library(processR)`
- now you should be able to run the functions such as `pmacroModel` etc

Basically you need both `processr` and `processR`!

BTW, the same issue is the R terminal. You have to run as `sudo` and follow the above steps to get everything working!

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial page you references, install `processr` (not `processR`) in the following way:

```
# Run this if devtools isn't installed.
# install.packages("devtools")

# Run to install "processr"
devtools::install_github("markhwhiteii/processr")
```

After that successfully completes, `processr::model1` will be defined.

When running the code in this post it produces a result:

```
set.seed(1839)
var1 <- rnorm(100)
cond <- rbinom(100, 1, .5)
var2 <- var1 * cond + rnorm(100)
df3 <- data.frame(var1, var2, cond)
head(df3)

mod1result <- processr::model1(iv = "var1", dv = "var2", mod = "cond", data = df3)

mod1result
## # A tibble: 6 x 5
##   term          estimate std.error statistic       p.value
##   <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
## 1 intercept       0.133      0.146     0.916 0.362        
## 2 var1            0.0696     0.156     0.445 0.657        
## 3 cond           -0.173      0.200    -0.865 0.389        
## 4 interaction     0.854      0.213     4.01  0.000118     
## 5 when cond = 0   0.0696     0.156     0.445 0.657        
## 6 when cond = 1   0.924      0.144     6.40  0.00000000577
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I do have the package already installed. Attempt to install again retuns: `Skipping install of 'processr' from a github remote, the SHA1 (7d3a3860) has not changed since last install. Use `force = TRUE` to force installation`

Comment: If `force = TRUE` does not work, perhaps run `devtools::uninstall("processr)`.

Comment: Also, have you tried to restart your R session after install ?

Comment: I just restarted the whole computer again. and still doesn't work!

Comment: Do you get the same error ? FWIW, your code is working for me.

Comment: Also, when you reinstall `processr`, can you please confirm that the install produced no errors.

Comment: the commands `remove.packages("processr")` and `remove.packages("processR")` both fail with `(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)` and the `devtools::uninstall("processr)` goes to a strange mode showing `+` as the cursor!

Comment: Change `devtools::uninstall("processr)` to `devtools::uninstall("processr")`. You are missing a double quote.

Comment: If you run the following, `sapply(.libPaths(), function(x) list.files(x, pattern = "processr"))`, you should see which path from `.libPaths()` contains `processr`, which will confirm it is installed. This is after you re-install it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208090/discussion-between-steveb-and-foad).