# Can not install processr and procesR on Windows

Tags: r, processr

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291182/4999991), I am trying to install the package (running R64 as admin on Windows):

```
devtools::install_github("markhwhiteii/processr")
```

or

```
devtools::install_github("cardiomoon/processR")
```

However, I get the error message:

> Error: Failed to install 'processr' from GitHub:
>     (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package 'digest'

no matter which update option I select. Running the command `.libPaths()` I found the packages installation folder `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library` and manually deleted the `digest` package and reinstalled it with `package.install("digest")`.  But I still get the same error! I would appreciate it if you could help me understand what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

Comment: Did you try installing or updating the 'digest' package?

Comment: @Ashish indeed. Same issue. I deleted `digest` manually and installed back again with no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to say no when `install_github` asks if it should replace digest.

If it still fails for some reason (and I can't see why; neither package requires a specific version of digest and you've reinstalled it in any case), then the problem is that devtools itself uses digest, so it can't be removed as long as devtools is loaded. So you can't use `install_github`.

You have a couple of options:

- Clone the repo, then from the command line, run `R CMD INSTALL .` in that directory. Note that you'll need to insert the path to your R executable.
- Install from the GitHub archive of the master branch: `install.packages("https://github.com/markhwhiteii/processr/archive/master.tar.gz")`

Comment: I know how to clone the repo, but I don't know how to "open it in RStudio". Would you be kind to give me a vinilla R solution? I'm not sure if I want to install another software for th emoment.

Comment: As in, open the folder that contains the repo

Comment: regarding your first point, "say no when install_github asks if it should replace digest". I have already tried different options from 1 to 4 with no help.

Comment: I opened r as admin in the folder where I cloned the [repo](https://github.com/markhwhiteii/processr.git) and then ran `devtools::install()`. The same error.

Comment: I ignored the first steps and the `install.packages("https://github.com/markhwhiteii/processr/archive/master.tar.gz")` solved the problem somehow.

Comment: Nuking the R installation didn't help either. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60296961/4999991) are the reproducible steps for installing the package. I'm not getting good vibes from R so far.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to install the `markhwhiteii/processr` package:

- `install.packages("devtools")`
- `library(devtools)`
- `install.packages("https://github.com/markhwhiteii/processr/archive/master.tar.gz")`

for testing the instalation:

- `library(processr)`
- `processr::model1`

Sent [a PR on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/markhwhiteii/processr/pull/4).

and if you want to run R in the Jupyter environment just follow [the instructions](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel) to install and regsiter the kernel:

- `install.packages('IRkernel')`
- `IRkernel::installspec()`